# Is it 4-days, 4 days or 4-day?

Tags: numbers

If I am writing a tour description, what is the correct way to write up days and nights? For example in this short description:

'Summit Java's highest peak for sunrise, trek through lava fields and camp in stunning spots. 4 days, 3 nights.

Your adventure includes:

- 4-day guided hiking
- 3 nights camping
- Return transfer from....'

etc

Would it be different if it was 1 day, or 2 days? (or 1-day or 2-days?)

We are trying to stick to AP style, but it is not clear on this subject.
If someone can clear this up we'd be very grateful!

Comment: What you've written sounds fine to me.

Comment: Your use of the hyphen is correct: it indicates the number is used to modify another word which is used in adjectivial form.  I'd note that many style guides recommend writing all numbers less than 10 as words rather than numerals.